# CDROM recognized, but cannot mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0

Tags: mount, dvd, cd-drive

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 and want to open some CDs and DVDs. While on my old PC running Ubuntu Server, they can be mounted easily, on my laptop they are not mounted.

I tried:

```
$ sudo lshw -C disk
  *-cdrom                   
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: DVDRAM GU71N
       vendor: HL-DT-ST
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: AS00
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/cdrom
 ...

$ sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom0
mount: /media/cdrom0: no medium found on /dev/sr0.
```

Since it communicates with the hardware, I don't think there is a hardware problem. Recently I upgraded from 16.10 to 17.04 and then to 17.10. Not sure if that's related, but I think the hardware doesn't have any problems.

How to solve this? How can I mount the CD drive? How can I do this automatically, eventually?

Comment: `no medium found on /dev/sr0` when we know there's one typically indicates hardware failure (it can happen with CDs and DVDs only or both and the drive being detected is meaningless, the problem is often the laser).

Comment: If you have a problem with all CDs/DVDs on this driver, it is probably dead. The electronics part to communicate with the host may be ok, but the mechanical part to spin up disks, move the read, start the laser and so on, could be dead and is separated.

Comment: @MichaelBay *the problem is often the laser* –– Didn't know that. Opened the CDROM, cleared the laser glass with my finger (I know it's not the smoothest thing), and it worked! Haha! You can post an answer now. Thanks!

Comment: AU is about Ubuntu, not hardware troubleshooting. Cleaning a dusty lens hardly merits an answer on its own.

Comment: @MichaelBay I didn't use this CDROM for years and I think dust was on the lens. I was suggesting answering because others may be in the same situation. :)

Comment: The question itself may be considered off topic.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to mount my dvd drive on usb and getting 'no medium found on /dev/sr0'. The solution is trivial: there was no CD in my dvd reader. When I put CD in, it mounted correctly.